# Vim: call consecutive functions in <C-R> mapping

Tags: vim

I have two functions `Foo()` and `Bar()` which I want to call consecutively in a `<C-R>` mapping:

```
inoremap <silent> <CR> <C-R>=(pumvisible() ? Foo().Bar(): "\<lt>CR>")<CR>
```

However in this way only `Foo()` is called and `Bar()` is ignored. Is there a way to have a mapping that calls both functions one after the other one?

**EDIT:** `Foo()` is a function to close the popup menu and `Bar()` a function to expand snippets. Therefore I first need to close the popup menu and then expand the snippet. I can do this with the following `<expr>` mapping (where `Foo()` corresponds to `neocomplete#close_popup()` and `Bar()` to `UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()`:

```
inoremap <silent><expr><CR> pumvisible() ?
    \ neocomplete#close_popup()."\<C-R>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()\<CR>" : "\<CR>"
```

I was wondering how to do the same directly with a pure `<C-R>` mapping.

Comment: There is no prob with your code. Can be more specific to what `Foo()` and `Bar()` do ?

Comment: @DOOM I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The first thing to do is to get rid of `<silent>` until you are finished debugging.

Comment: @benjifisher When I get rid of `<silent>` the only thing that still happens is that `Foo()` is called but `Bar()` is not. So my question is: given a `<C-R>` mapping, what is the proper way to call consecutively two function (where the second functions uses input generated by the first one)?

Comment: I think you are jumping to a conclusion.  Is this really about `<C-R>`?  Is it really about mapping?  Does it have something to do with the ternary operator?  (My guesses:  no to all three.)  The next step in debugging is to simplify, isolate your problem.  Does `:echo Foo().Bar()` work as you expect?  If so, build up from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your new code is wrong with `\<C-R>=` and `\<CR>` in the same includes(`"`).

Anyways, I don't use `neocomplete` so this is not a exact solution to your problem.

```
function! TESTIN_G()
    return "<TESTING>"
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <CR>  pumvisible() ? "<C-R>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<CR>".TESTIN_G() : "\<CR>"
```

This link may help you . But it refers to older version of the plugins [Neocomplete-UltiSnips](https://answers.launchpad.net/ultisnips/+question/241608)

Answer (score 1):

In general, this works:

```
fun! Foo()
    return "foo-"
endfun
fun! Bar()
    echomsg 'in bar'
    return 'bar'
endfun
inoremap <F12> <C-r>=Foo().Bar()<CR>
```

This will insert `foo-bar` when pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> in insert mode.

You didn't exactly write whether `Bar()` is actually called (and only its returned keys are ignored, which can happen depending on what `Foo()` returns), or whether it is not invoked at all (which I would find odd, and should only happen in case of thrown exceptions from `Foo()`).

Integrating complex plugins like Neocomplete and UltiSnips is difficult. You seem to have found a workaround; I'd be content with that, because (as I've shown with my example) the general case does work as expected.